# Long time for compilation of latex file

Tags: floats, compiling

I am compiling a single chapter of my thesis using iiscthesis style file given here.
http://etd.ncsi.iisc.ernet.in/instructions/templates.htm

While including the

```
\begin {figure}
\end {figure}
```

the file takes a longer time for compilation even with only a single chapter.
The compilation happens normally when there is no figure environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn,english]{iiscthes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{babel}
\pagestyle{bfheadings}
\title{Introduction}
\date{}     
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\chapter [Introduction] {Introduction}
\noindent Inroduction
\cite{kuhn}. ..
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Figure1}
\end{figure}

\bibliography{biblio,chapter1}

\end{document}
```

Hi,
Now I have a new code instead of the earlier one. If I make any changes to the above code, the compilation again takes a lot of time. How can that be solved.
The class file is also different from the previous one. How can I attach the class file to this question?

Comment: Sorry, this gotta be a mistake. I opened up `thessamp.tex` and found `documentstyle`.

Comment: The upshot: Do check whether a template is available that uses LaTeX2e (hint: the first instruction should be `\documentclass`) instead of LaTeX2.09 (where files start with `\documentstyle`). LaTeX2e has been *the* standard for LaTeX since 1994. High time to update a few templates, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for posting some more detailed code. Note that the `subfigure` package is deprecated; for sure, you shouldn't load it since the `subfig` package is loaded as well. Do you need the `subfloat` package at all? Finally, the `latexsym` package is also deprecated and should probably not be loaded.

Comment: A synctex file gets generated while the tex is compiled. In case the compilation takes time it shows the status of being busy. How to stop this file

Comment: That does not work. In case I do dvi - ps, the error is "This is dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) dvips: ! unexpected eof on DVI file" Why does this happen?

Comment: While compiling the tex, an error occurs "Unused Global Option [English]" How to remove this error?

Comment: How can I solve the error "This is dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) dvips: ! unexpected eof on DVI file"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
          Entering LaTeX 2.09 COMPATIBILITY MODE
 *************************************************************
    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!   

 This mode attempts to provide an emulation of the LaTeX 2.09
 author environment so that OLD documents can be successfully
 processed. It should NOT be used for NEW documents!

 New documents should use Standard LaTeX conventions and start
 with the \documentclass command.

 Compatibility mode is UNLIKELY TO WORK with LaTeX 2.09 style
 files that change any internal macros, especially not with
 those that change the FONT SELECTION or OUTPUT ROUTINES.

 Therefore such style files MUST BE UPDATED to use
          Current Standard LaTeX: LaTeX2e.
 If you suspect that you may be using such a style file, which
 is probably very, very old by now, then you should attempt to
 get it updated by sending a copy of this error message to the
 author of that file.
 *************************************************************
```

I think the message is pretty clear.