# cls file not compiling subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I'm trying to compile my code using my institute's `.cls` file. If I use a `subfigure` environment, it doesn't compile at all and does not produce a log file. The mouse pointer just keeps rotating. If I comment out the `subfigure` environment, then it compiles perfectly. Any thoughts on how to deal with this?
The .sty file that I'm using can be downloaded from http://etd.ncsi.iisc.ernet.in/instructions/templates.htm and click on the 'Style Files for LATEX template'.

```
\documentstyle[12pt,amsmath,graphicx,epsfig,lscape,eepic,epic,pdflscape,subfig,threeparttable,cite,amssymb,caption,enumerate,bm,multirow,appendix,titletoc]{iiscthes}

\begin{document}
\title{\bfseries A Three}
\submitdate{August 2016}
\dept{Dept}
\maketitle
\begin{frontmatter}
\newpage
\begin{center}
\textbf{CERTIFICATE}
\end{center} 
\newpage
\end{frontmatter}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\include{Chapter1/Chap1_Introduction}
\end{document}

Chapter1/Chap1_Introduction starts as \chapter{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{./Chapter1/Temp_diff_1884}
  \caption{1884}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{./Chapter1/Temp_diff_1950}
  \caption{1950}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Average  from 1884 to 2014}
\label{fig:Time}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Which document class are you using? How should be provide help if we don't know the details? Please add a minimal example (a compilable document!)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The question is, unfortunately, not answerable, unless you add a pointer to the class and also an example of how you use the `subfigure` environment.

Comment: Your document starts with `documentstyle` which is obsolete for more than two decades. Do you see the **huge** warning while compiling?

Comment: [Long time for compilation of latex file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277244)

Comment: Thank you for the replies. i had tried \documentclass{} also. But the same problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

`subfigure` is not standard LaTeX, but rather is defined variously in different packages.  It is trivial to create one yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcounter{subfig}[figure]
\renewcommand{\thesubfig}{\alph{subfig}}

\newcommand{\subcaption}[1]% #1 = caption text
{\par\stepcounter{subfig}%
 \makebox[\textwidth]{\textbf{(\thesubfig)} #1}%
 \medskip\par}

\newenvironment{subfigure}[1]% width
{\begin{minipage}{#1}\let\caption=\subcaption}%
{\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
\caption{test 1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
\caption{test 2}
\end{subfigure}

\hfil\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}%
\caption{test 3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```