# Subfigure package caption positioning

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I would like to use subfigure package, since it allows to define the subfigure environment size in terms of columnwidth, etc.
However, I need to follow some formatting as:

- Figure title on top and align to left (Figure 1 - ...);
- Subcaptions below subfigures and
- Figure description on bottom and align to left.

How is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Updated: I've got almost what I need. Only references to subfigure are not right yet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcounter{subfig}[figure]
\renewcommand{\thesubfig}{\alph{subfig}}

\newcommand{\subcaption}[1]% #1 = caption text
{\par\stepcounter{subfig}%
\makebox[\textwidth]{\textbf{(\thesubfig)} #1}%
\medskip\par}

\newenvironment{subfigure}[1]% width
{\begin{minipage}{#1}\let\caption=\subcaption}%
{\end{minipage}}
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=endash,position=top]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{Test 1}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
\label{fig:test11}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
\label{fig:test12}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:test1}\\
{\footnotesize Source: Here comes the figures description.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{Test 2}
\begin{center}
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{center}
\label{fig:test2}
{\footnotesize Source: Here comes the figures description.}
\end{figure}

Figures \ref{fig:test1} is composed of \ref{fig:test11} e \ref{fig:test12}.

Figure \ref{fig:test2} is an ordinary include entry.
\end{document}
```

Here the output:
[image: result]

Comment: What's the difference between a figure "description" and a figure "caption"? Will the subcaptions have text, or just numbers? You shouldn't use the obsolete [`subfgure` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure). Use [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead. What `\documentclass` are you using? Are there any restrictions with using `subcaption` (perhaps because this is for a journal submission)?

Comment: I attached a link with a example to make clear the difference I meant. I don't intend to use text in subcaption, just (a), (b), and so on...
The \documentclass is a custom one of my university and this document is my thesis. I don't think there is a restriction about using subcaption. Could you provide an example, please?
[example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jrbk0malanx030/example.png?dl=0)

Comment: No link, no example...

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287919/cls-file-not-compiling-subfigure/287941?s=2|0.0000#287941

Comment: [Example right here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jrbk0malanx030/example.png?l=0)

Comment: I tried to use the example provided by @JohnKormylo in the related topic. I almost got what I need. How can I share with you my attempt here in the comments. Sorry, I am a very beginner.

Comment: I don't know about comments, but you can edit your question: insert code and images.  (CNTL V to paste)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, if this modification of your MWE do what you like to have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[justification=justified,
            singlelinecheck=false,
            labelsep=endash,
            position=top]{caption}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
\caption{Test 1}
\label{fig:test1}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
\caption{}
    \label{fig:test11}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
    \caption{}
\label{fig:test12}
    \end{subfigure}

{\footnotesize Source: Here comes the figures description.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
\caption{Test 2}
\label{fig:test2}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-c}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\footnotesize 
Source: Here comes the figures description.
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Figures \ref{fig:test1} is composed of \ref{fig:test11} e \ref{fig:test12}. 
Figure \ref{fig:test2} is an ordinary include entry.
\end{document}
```

In above MWE I remove your definitions of subfigure counter and environment and instead them use package `subcaption`. Beside this I put labels after captions where they should be (for correct referencing)

[image]

Comment: Perfect, @Zarko! I already knew about the \label after \caption. I just forgotten here.