# Automatically set Figure captions to Bold Italics

Tags: captions, subcaption

I wanted to be able to set the figure captions descriptions to bold Italics.  I am using the command `\usepackage[font={color=blue,bf},figurename=Fig.]{caption}` in the preamble to set the figure name to blue and bold.  I wanted to know how to append the preamble code to get the figure description to show up red bold italics (in this example Test 1 and Test 2 to show up red bold italics).  Thanks.

Here is the code (stolen from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296020/subfigure-package-caption-positioning)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{subcaption}

\usepackage[font={color=blue,bf},figurename=Fig.]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
\caption{Test 1}
\label{fig:test1}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
\caption{}
    \label{fig:test11}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
    \caption{}
\label{fig:test12}
    \end{subfigure}

{\footnotesize Source: Here comes the figures description.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
\caption{Test 2}
\label{fig:test2}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-c}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\footnotesize
Source: Here comes the figures description.
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Figures \ref{fig:test1} is composed of \ref{fig:test11} e \ref{fig:test12}.
Figure \ref{fig:test2} is an ordinary include entry.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you loading `caption` twice with different options?

Comment: `subcaption` loads it, too, so you need to load `caption` first, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=red,bf,it}}
```

Comment: I sincerely apologize for the mix-up, I actually wanted "Test 1" and "Test"  (the caption label description) in red Italics.  Sorry.  Thanks for your time and help.   I will modify my question now.

Comment: is there a command to change the caption description?   Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the ‘caption description’

Comment: in the modified question, the caption descriptions: "This is a description for Figure 1" and "This is a description for Figure 2" test font.  How to change just these caption descriptions to red bold italics?  Thanks.

Comment: If you mean the font for the caption text, it's simply `\captionsetup{textfont={red,nf,it}}`.The keys used by caption are `font` (for the whole caption), `labelfont` and `textfont`.

Comment: And how do you change the font in the referenced text? I would like to see Figure 1 italiced.

Comment: You can do that with `cleveref`: add to the preamble `\crefformat{figure}{\itshape\figurename~\thefigure}`.