# University dissertation package/cls table captions broken by subcaption and subfigure. How to fix?

Tags: tables, captions, subfloats, subcaption, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to write my dissertation, and I've run into an issue where the subcaption and subfig packages break the caption formatting for tables. For an example, the table number label shows up as,

"ABLE 2.1TABLETABLE 2.1" but should be "TABLE 2.1."

I've been relying on the subcaption package to make subfigures throughout my various papers, so removing the subcaption package is a very unsavory option. There are too many figures to reasonably recreate in Python as native subfigures. I also use subcaptions to make subtables. Plus, because formatting is one of the nastiest and most time consuming things in editing a dissertation, I would like to use my University's latex template.

I could attempt reformatting, in some roundabout way (i.e. putting a two column format in the figure while somehow managing to attach a single, centered caption, but I'm unaware of how to do that. I have searched for and approach similar to this idea, but all of the results that I found use subcaption, subfig, or subfigure.

Is there are an edit that could be performed to the cls file that could fix this without destroying the remaining formatting?
If not that, is there a simple way to prevent subfigure from interfering?
If not that either, is there a way to way to do what I need without using subcaption?

This is the link to the github repository for the template.
https://github.com/ndlib/nddiss

The below code must be used with the dissertation class linked above to reproduce this problem, or you could just add \usepackage{subcaption} and a singular table and tabular environment to template.tex. Take your pick.

```
\ProvidesFile{template.tex}
    [2016/10/16 v3.2016%
     Template file for NDdiss2e class]
\documentclass[draft]{nddiss2e}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter             % All the items before Chapter 1 go in ``frontmatter''

\title{ Title of Work }  % Title

\author{ Jane Doe }      % Author's name
\work{ Dissertation }    % ``Dissertation'' or ``Thesis''
\degaward{ Doctor of Philosophy }  % Degree you're aiming for.
                                   % Should be one of the following options:
                                   % ``Doctor of Philosophy'' (do NOT include ``in Subject'')
                                   % ``Master of Science \\ in \\ Subject''
\advisor{ John Public }  % Advisor's name
 % \secondadvisor{ }     % Second advisor, if used option ``twoadvisors''
\department{ }           % Name of the department

\maketitle               % The title page is created now



\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables



\mainmatter
 % Place the text body here.
 % \include{chapter-one}
 % Begin each chapter with \chapter{Title}.
 \begin{table}[]
     \centering
     \caption{a caption}
     \begin{tabular}{c|c}
          &  \\
          & 
     \end{tabular}
     \label{tab:my_label}
 \end{table}


\bibliographystyle{nddiss2e}
 \bibliography{ }           % input the bib-database file name


\end{document}

%%
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `template.tex'.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.  Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Without knowing what is in nddiss2e.cls it is difficult to tell what the problem is.  If you remove `\usepackage{subcaption}` what sort of error messages do you get?  Worst case, you can create your own subfigure and subtable environments using minipages.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287919/cls-file-not-compiling-subfigure

Comment: @JohnKormylo Are you wanting me to post the entire cls file? As far as I know that is generally frowned upon. I provided the link to the github repository in the problem statement.